# Property, indexer, or event 'CoreWindow.PointerPressed' is not supported by the language

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, event-handling

I have a Xamarin Forms UWP project which i am trying to add a handler to the Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed which was working perfectly fine, until i went to build again and now i get this issue.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed += CoreWindow_PointerPressed;
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
}

private void CoreWindow_PointerPressed(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.PointerEventArgs args)
{
    tcPageTimeOut?.RestartTimer();
}

private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
{
    tcPageTimeOut?.RestartTimer();
}
```

the same happens when assigning a handler to the KeyDown Event.

Error   CS1545  Property, indexer, or event 'CoreWindow.PointerPressed' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods 'CoreWindow.add_PointerPressed(TypedEventHandler)' or 'CoreWindow.remove_PointerPressed(EventRegistrationToken)'

min version: 16299

target version: 18362

i noticed that the assembley files windows.foundation.foundationcontract & windows.foundation.universalApiContract are version 16299 which i assume are correct as that's the min version. but should they match the target version?

Does anyone know have to either fix this issue or have another way to capture pointpressed application wide?

Thanks

Comment: ,**which was working perfectly fine, until i went to build again and now i get this issue**, can you provide more code about using CoreWindow.PointerPressed?

Comment: i have checked and i can access Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed from my UWP project but not my main project? is there a setting stopping this?

Comment: I try to add Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed event in PCL ContentPage to reproduce your issue, but failing, so can you provide one simple sample here?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT when you say you are failing, is that failing to reproduce my issue which means you are successfully adding?